# App permissions on Facebook different between browser and app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an iOS/Android app with Facebook sign in. The app sign in correctly asks for basic and extended permissions (email, post on behalf).
However, while trying to authorize the app via browser on PC (safari or Chrome) Facebook only asks for basic user info permissions.

I'm following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ and everything works except for this difference in what permissions Facebook asks for.

Any suggestion on how to make it work correctly on browser too?

Comment: Did you go through whole process of granting permissions? If i remember correctly, for PC browsers, process was split in 2 steps, first -requesting basic permissions, second - extended permissions (after you click approve on basic permissions)

Comment: have you checked your permission settings in the the app?

Comment: yes, as I said, the app authorization correctly asks for basic info, email, post on behalf, while the browser authorization only asks for basic info, neither goes through a second step after granting access to basic info. If I click on the "Preview Auth Dialog" the auth dialog is correct, but then on the browser it just behaves differently.